# Opera and FireFox cannot read CSS3 rotate value

Tags: jquery, css, cross-browser, rotation

I cannot read a CSS3 transform rotate value in:

- Opera 9.62
- Opera 10.51
- FireFox 4.01

Works fine in IE, Chrome and Safari, but not in these three above.
Here is the source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        div {
            -webkit-transform:     rotate(-5deg);
            -moz-transform:        rotate(-5deg);
            -o-transform:        rotate(-5deg);
            -ms-transform:        rotate(-5deg);
            transform:            rotate(-5deg);
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            // tries to read the CSS rotate data
            // starts by reading -webkit-transform, if it
            // fails then read -moz-transform and so on
            var getRotation = function ($e) {
                var value = $e.css('-webkit-transform');
                if (value === undefined) {
                    value = $e.css('-moz-transform');
                    if (value === undefined) {
                        value = $e.css('-o-transform');
                        if (value === undefined) {
                            value = $e.css('-ms-transform');
                            if (value === undefined) {
                                value = $e.css('transform');
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return value === undefined? '' : value;
            };

            var returnValue = getRotation($("div"));
            alert(returnValue === ''?
                "Failed to get rotation info!" : 
                "Got it: " + returnValue);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>rotated</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[live sample on jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ruisoftware/gq2YL/1/)

So, I want to use jquery `css()` to read the rotation angle, but strangely, Opera 10.51 and FF 4.01 (and below) cannot read it, although the `div` is rendered correctly with a rotation effect.

This looks like a jQuery bug or a browser bug. **Does anyone have a workaround for Opera/FF?**

If you get an alert saying "Got it" then it works.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yep, doesn't work. So is this really a question or just a statement? I'd rather see that you file this as a bug to either the jQuery devs or the browser devs.

Comment: Thanks, I also suspected this was a bug. Sorry for the unclear question. I just edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out the problem. The problem was on my code, that was not checking properly the return values from the `css()` getter.

Before I had:

```
if (value === undefined) {...
```

The problem was fixed, by changing the above condition to:

```
if (notDefined(value)) {...
```

where `notDefined` is the function

```
var notDefined = function(value) {
    return value == null || value == undefined || value == "" || value == "none";
}
```

To be cross browser, I need to compare against all these 3 cases, not only undefined.

You can see the update [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ruisoftware/qhgL9/)

It works for all the latest versions of IE (also IE7 and 8), Firefox, Safari, Chrome and Opera.

Comment: Ah yeah. I should have seen that! Why not doing the proper cross-browser-friendly way? `if (typeof varName === "undefined") { ... }`